# Slick dynamically filter by a list of columns and values

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to create a query in slick with dynamic filtering. I have a `Seq[(String, String)]` where the first element of the tuple is the column name while the second is the value against which make the filter.

In pseudo code, I want to do something like this:

```
val filters: Seq[(String, String)]
val query = filters.foldLeft(entityTable) {
    case(query, (column, value)) => query.filter(select(column) === value)
}
```

I already have a function `def select(name: String): Rep[_]` that returns the column `Rep` starting from its name that works well but I don't know how to get all the implicits needed to make the `===` function (or others comparison functions) work.

Is there any way to make such a dynamic filtering in slick?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier when you try with `query.filter(x => check(x, column, value))` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is !

I use this method

```
private def applyOperator[T](left: Rep[T], right: Rep[T], operator: String)(implicit om: OptionMapper2[T, T, Boolean, T, T, Boolean]): Rep[Boolean] = {
    operator match {
      case "==" => new BaseColumnExtensionMethods(left) === right
      case "!=" => new BaseColumnExtensionMethods(left) =!= right
      case "like" => new StringColumnExtensionMethods(left.asInstanceOf[Rep[String]]) like right.asInstanceOf[Rep[String]] //Breaks if T is not String
    }
  }
```

Then you can write something like

```
val filters: Seq[(String, String)]
val query = filters.foldLeft(entityTable) {
    case(query, (column, value)) => query.filter(applyOperator(yourFunctionForColumnFromName(column),value, "=="))
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like this, do you have a full example?

Comment: Well, the full example would be IP of my employer ^^ if you have specific questions, please feel free to ask them on SO !
One thing to keep in mind is that forcing T to BaseTypedType will help a lot with writing the boilerplate (and restrict what you can search on, so it's a trade off !)

Comment: in your example "right" is defined as a "Rep[T]", but right is the value-string. So how can i convert the value-string to a Rep[String] ? As far as i understood the thread-example, the value is also defined as a string-parameter?

Comment: @Raste there's an implicit conversion in slick, so you don't have to worry about it actually.

Comment: @C4stor, This is really helpful, Thanks.
How can we add inSet filter to this function? inSet accepts an Iterable[T].

Comment: I didn't find how to do it directly, so I expanded inset user filters to huge x == a or x == b or .... ^^