# Pass map to slick filter and filter by the values in the map

Tags: scala, slick

I'm new to scala, and, I'm trying to pass a map i.e. `Map[String, Any]("from_type" -> "Admin", "from_id" -> 1)` to my service for dynamic filtering. I'm trying to avoid writing my code like this `filter(_.fromType === val && _.fromId === val2)`

When trying this example [Slick dynamically filter by a list of columns and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224182/slick-dynamically-filter-by-a-list-of-columns-and-values)

I get a Type mismatch. `Required Function1[K, NotInfered T]` `Found: Rep[Boolean]`

Service code:

```
val query = TableQuery[UserTable]

def all(perPage: Int page: Int, listFilters: Map[String, Any]): Future[ResultPagination[User]] = {

  val baseQuery = for {
   items <- query.filter( listFilters ).take(perPage).drop(page).result // <----I want to filter here
    total <- query.length.result
  } yield ResultPagination[User](items, total)
  db.run(baseQuery)
}
```

Table code:

```
def fromId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("from_id")
def fromType: Rep[String] = column[String]("from_type")

def columnToRep(column: String): Rep[_] = {
  column match {
    case "from_type" = this.fromType
    case "from_id" = this.fromId
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would not recommend to use `Map[String, Any]` construction, because of using `Any` you are loosing type safety: for instance you can pass to the function by mistake `Map("fromId" -> "1")` and compile won't help identify issue.

I guess, what you want is to pass some kind of structure representing variative filter. And `Query.filterOpt` can help you in this case. You can take a look usage examples at: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.2/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering

Please, see code example below:

```
  // Your domain filter structure. None values will be ignored
  // So `UserFilter()` - will match all.
  case class UserFilter(fromId: Option[Int] = None, fromString: Option[String] = None)

  def all(perPage: Int, page: Int, filter: UserFilter): Future[ResultPagination[User]] = {
    val baseQuery = for {
      items <- {
        query
          .filterOpt(filter.fromId)(_.fromId === _)
          .filterOpt(filter.fromString)(_.fromType === _)
          .take(perPage)
          .drop(page)
          .result
      }
      total <- query.length.result
    } yield ResultPagination[User](items, total)
    db.run(baseQuery)
  }
```

And this will type safe.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I see a similar solution while searching. im assuming there is no other way around it. Thanks